# Column hide after exporting to excel using Angular

Tags: angular

I want to download all the data from a server in Excel format using Angular, however I want to hide a few columns in the downloaded file using Angular? How to do it?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I could delete the column using Angular but couldn't hide it.

Comment: I know there are packages out there that allow you to manipulate xlsx files in the frontend, however, your frontend would end with access to the whole file which means a user could access the complete file with very little effort. I would recommend removing those columns on the server before download if the information in them is supposed to remain private for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You would first have to know the format of the data that is sent by the server as soon as you make a get request to it. If json you will have to prepare a logic to handle the data by traversing it with a foreach loop and handle it first to use an xlsx library.

For example, you will need to make an HTTP request to retrieve the data from the server. You can use Angular's HttpClient library for this.

If the format is already a blob of data that comes from the server, you can treat it according to the use of the libraries.

Make sure you have the file-saver library installed to save the file on the client, as well as the xlsx library.

To install use the npm commands:

```
npm install file-saver --save
bower install file-saver

npm install xlsx
```

More information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

More information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

And do something like that, for example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  downloadExcelFile() {
    const url = 'SERVER_URL_FOR_EXCEL_FILE'; // Replace with the actual URL of the file

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    });

    // Make an HTTP request to download the Excel file
    this.http.get(url, { headers, responseType: 'blob' })
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          console.error('Error while downloading the file:', error);
          return throwError(error);
        })
      )
      .subscribe(response => {
        const contentDispositionHeader = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
        const fileName = this.getFileNameFromContentDisposition(contentDispositionHeader);

        // Create a Blob with the downloaded file
        const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });

        // Read the Blob as a workbook using the xlsx library
        XLSX.read(blob, { type: 'blob' }, (err, wb) => {
          if (err) throw err;

          // Get the desired worksheet (replace 'Sheet1' with the name of your sheet)
          const ws = wb.Sheets['Sheet1'];

          // Hide the desired columns
        ws['!cols'] = [
        { hidden: false }, // Assuming the first column is not hidden
        { hidden: false }, // Assuming the second column is not hidden
        { hidden: true },  // Hide the third column (index 2)
        { hidden: true },  // Hide the fourth column (index 3)
        ];

          // Save the modified XLSX file
          const modifiedBlob = XLSX.write(wb, { type: 'blob' });

          saveAs(modifiedBlob, fileName); // Save the modified file on the client with the correct name
        });
      });
  }

  private getFileNameFromContentDisposition(header: string): string {
    const matches = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/.exec(header);
    if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
      return matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
    }
    return 'download.xlsx'; // Default name if the file name cannot be obtained
  }
}
```

In the line `const matches = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/.exec(header);` uses a regular expression (regex ) to fetch the portion of the header string that contains the filename. The regular expression looks for filename followed by an equals sign = and then captures the value of the filename.

If json you will have to process your json before using the xlsx library to support the conversion, something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx'; // Import the xlsx library

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  downloadProcessedExcelFile() {
    const url = 'SERVER_URL_FOR_JSON_DATA'; // Replace with the actual URL of the JSON data

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    });

    // Make an HTTP request to download JSON data
    this.http.get(url, { headers })
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          console.error('Error while downloading JSON data:', error);
          return throwError(error);
        })
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        // Convert the JSON data to an object suitable for XLSX
        const xlsxData = this.convertJSONToXLSXData(data);

        // Create an XLSX workbook with the data
        const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(xlsxData);
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

        // Save the XLSX file on the client
        const blob = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'blob' });
        const fileName = 'data.xlsx';
        saveAs(blob, fileName);
      });
  }

  private convertJSONToXLSXData(jsonData: any[]): any[] {
    // Implement the logic to convert your JSON data into a format suitable for XLSX
    // The example below simply assumes your JSON data is an array of objects
    // Each object represents a row in the spreadsheet, and the object keys represent columns

    // Example of converting JSON data into a format suitable for XLSX
    const xlsxData = jsonData.map(item => ({
      Column1: item.field1,
      Column2: item.field2,
      // Add more columns as needed
    }));

    return xlsxData;
  }
}
```